# I'm retrieving data from firebase into list view, but I want the data to show up in justified format without the use of webview, any suggestions?

Tags: java, android

I just want my data from fire base to show justified in my list view I tried web views on other places where I used text views but it's super slow and super heavy.

I tried web views but the slow down my application and take a second to display the data, the data on my firebase is text, I found out that android does not support justification, so I removed the text views and used web views but I can't remove my list. I need a method so that I can show justified data into the list.

This is my code and simple list

```
public class Food extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private ListView listView;
    private List<DataL> datalist;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listFood);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int days = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("Days"));

        datalist = new ArrayList<>();
        final DataListAdapter adapter = new DataListAdapter(this,datalist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        if (days <= 120){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("1");
        }else if (days <=180){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("2");
        }else if (days <=300){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("3");
        }else if (days <= 365){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("4");
        }else if (days <= 730){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("5");
        }else if(days <= 1095){
            reference = database.getReference("food").child("6");
        }

        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                DataL dl = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataL.class);
                datalist.add(dl);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use JustifiedTextView instead of normal textview in your adapter layout like this:
https://github.com/amilcar-sr/JustifiedTextView

Comment: well that is not working for me i tried, also can you specify a way in which  the text can be shown in justified inside the list view?

Comment: In your DataListAdapter layout file's textview you can replace above JustifiedTextView. what is problem you are facing? share your complete code here.